# ¿Cómo instancio 10 togglebutton sin tener que escribirlos uno por uno?

Tags: java, android

Quiero instanciar este grupo de `togglebutton` pero si hubiese una manera de instanciarlos todos sin tener que hacer este tipo de lista, podría hacerse con un `for` pienso yo, pero no se me ocurre la manera.

```
    tb1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb1);
    tb2=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb2);
    tb3=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb3);
    tb4=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb4);
    tb5=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb5);
    tb6=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb6);
    tb7=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb7);
    tb8=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb8);
    tb9=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb9);
    tb10=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb10);
```

Adicional a esto los mismo quiero cuando utilice el `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
    tb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    tb10.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
```

Solo quiero hacer eso mismo pero más corto ya que en el proyecto podría llegar fácilmente a los 20 botones. por cierto el `toggleListener` lo saco de aquí:

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    boolean avoidRecursions = false;

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if(avoidRecursions) return;
        avoidRecursions = true;

        if(!isChecked)
        {
            buttonView.setChecked(true);
            avoidRecursions = false;
            return;
        }


        if(buttonView != tb1 && tb1.isChecked()) tb1.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb2 && tb2.isChecked()) tb2.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb3 && tb3.isChecked()) tb3.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb4 && tb4.isChecked()) tb4.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb5 && tb5.isChecked()) tb5.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb6 && tb6.isChecked()) tb6.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb7 && tb7.isChecked()) tb7.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb8 && tb8.isChecked()) tb8.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb9 && tb9.isChecked()) tb9.setChecked(false);
        else if(buttonView != tb10 && tb10.isChecked()) tb10.setChecked(false);

        avoidRecursions = false;
    }
};
```

Para que solo pueda estar un botón a la vez presionado

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues yo creo que de instanciarlos uno por uno, no te salvas... Perooo si puedes simplificarlo un poco usando ButterKnife, para importarlo a tu projecto tienes que agregar estas lineas al Gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Posteriormente lo usas de esta manera:

```
@BindView(R.id.t1)
ToggleButton t1;
@BindView(R.id.t2)
ToggleButton t2;
...
```

Como te das cuenta al mismo tiempo creas los objectos los instancias.

Posteriormente en el metodo **onCreate** de tu aplicacion es NECESARIO que ingreses esta linea:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Solo la tienes que llamar una vez para TODOS los objectos.

Para añadirles el listener tienes opciones mas simples.
Lo que te recomiendo es que crees una Lista de ToogleButton donde guardes todos tus elementos de la siguiente manera:

```
toggleButtons.add(t1);
toggleButtons.add(t2);
...
```

Una vez los tienes en la lista, obtienes todos los elementos de la lista y les asignas el mismo listener de la siguiente manera:

```
for (ToggleButton toggleButton : toggleButtons) {
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener());
}
```

Para el ToggleListener puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener() {
    return new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
            //Implementas la logica de tu toggle

            //Recorre entre todos tus botones y los pone desmarcados sino corresponden a 'buttonView'
            for (ToggleButton toggleButton : toggleButtons) {
                if (buttonView != toggleButton && toggleButton.isChecked()) toggleButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Al final quedaría algo así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.t1)
ToggleButton t1;
@BindView(R.id.t2)
ToggleButton t2;

ArrayList<ToggleButton> toggleButtons = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    toggleButtons.add(t1);
    toggleButtons.add(t2);

    for (ToggleButton toggleButton : toggleButtons) {
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener());
    }
}

private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener() {
    return new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
            //Implementas la logica de tu toggle

            //Recorre entre todos tus botones y los pone desmarcados sino corresponden a 'buttonView'
            for (ToggleButton toggleButton : toggleButtons) {
                if (buttonView != toggleButton && toggleButton.isChecked()) toggleButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Hay un problema, al oprimir un botón la primer vez pues lo oprime bien pero quiero oprimir otro y al primer click se desmarca el que ya había presionado y me toca presionar otra vez para que se marque el nuevo que quiero, busco que me presione de una y que el anterior se desmarque solo.

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo resolvería de la siguiente manera:
En el xml al Layout padre (El que contiene todos los elementos) le asignas un id
Por ejemplo si fuera un `LinearLayout`( no sé que estarás usando pero funciona igual).

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewGroup" <!--cualquier id (por cierto aqui no se puede comentar) -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ... <!--Los demas atributos -->
        >
<!-- Todos los ToggleButton que quieras-->
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tg1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#1"/>
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tg2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#2"/>
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tg3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#3"/>
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tg4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#4"/>
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tg5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

En el método `onCreate()` de tu actividad Java agregas esto:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.viewGroup);//aqui busca el id del LinearLayout pero lo cargas como ViewGroup
eventosToggleButtons(viewGroup);
```

Y el método que hace toda la magia de manera recursiva...

```
private void eventosToggleButtons(ViewGroup layout) {
        View child;
        ToggleButton toggleButton;
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {

            child = layout.getChildAt(i);

            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                eventosToggleButtons((ViewGroup) child);
            } else if ( child instanceof ToggleButton){
                toggleButton = (ToggleButton) child;
                toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "My id: "+ view.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Eso sería todo, el mismo método realmente yo lo uso con otros propósitos, no acostumbro a asignar eventos así pero para fines prácticos cumple con lo que necesitas.

Si te ayudó o si es la respuesta que buscabas recuerda darle hacía arriba o marcarla como correcta. Igualmente un gracias no se desprecia y si no es lo que buscabas pues también comenta para ayudarte en lo que necesites.

Saludos!

Comment: Es muy útil me funcionó bien la lectura de cada botón gracias, pero tengo otra duda, tenia un método que me dejaba un botón en false cuando presionaba otro, cuando incluyo lo que me diste oprimo varios botones y todos se quedan presionados, Abría modo de incluir esa comprobación al método que me diste?

Comment: Buenos días, publica otra pregunta, y agrega lo que tienes en interfaz, lo que quieres hacer con los botones y el código que tienes para ayudarte. Saludos amigo.